# Using Views in Doctrine 2 with Symfony 2

Tags: database, view, doctrine-orm, symfony

I have a database for orders (simplified):
order: {id, shipment, discount, date}
order_item: {id, order_id, name, amount, price}

If I want to get the full price (SUM(item prices)+shipment-discount) I could of course ad a method to my Order class that does the query. On the other hand, it would be handy to have a view on order that includes the full price.

Is it possible to integrate that into a Doctrine2 entity object? Is it even possible to generate such a view via annotations in the class, as I am maintaining my database layout with Symfony/Doctrine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have Doctrine Entity and EntityRepository.

Queries should go to Repository Classes as a method. A mysql-view is just a query. A Repository Class returns one or more Entity classes.. I.E Row in Database Table.

**Please provide some code and schema, to get better answers.**

This could go to Order Entity:

```
public function getOrderTotal() {
    $sum = 0.0;
    foreach ($this->getOrderItems() as $item) {
     //Process 
    }
    return $sum;
}
```

**Native MySQL Views handling and generating is not supported by Doctrine2.**

Comment: Excuse me, "Yes for sure" what? When I said "Is it possible to integrate that into a Doctrine2 entity object?" I didn't mean to write a method with a query but to let Doctrine generate a view in the database (that I can also use from outside).
Your answer seems to be more "No" to that.

Comment: Again, I Doctrine2 has not quite strange coding standards, then I don't think the Repository class is the correct location. From an OOP-point of view I would expect to retrieve a property of an entity from the entity itself, not from some "repository". As far as I understand, one of the advantages of doctrine2 is that you can work with normal object instead of classes inheriting from doctrine classes.

Comment: You misunderstood. You work with Objects extending Doctrine Entity. The advantage is, that you dont have top work with plain php arrays like mysql_fetch_assoc gives you, for example.

Comment: I don't quite understand. I do not extend anything for my Entites. The Doc also says you don't: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html
Also, while the class "Entity" exists, it is final.

Answer (score 0):

mmm ¿Posible? I don't know. I think doing a custom repository for these entity would be the best. Entities with queries in its methods are not clean. 
Here there is an howto example working with entities and custom queries 
http://www.zalas.eu/doctrine2-and-symfony2

Comment: Hi, I don't think that is correct. The Howto describes a situation in with instances of the entity are queried (in my case for example "getOrdersForItem($item)"). I agree that such methods do not belong into the entitiy object.
What I want to do is getting a natural property of the entity, that just doesn't exist as a column because of rules of relational databases. In an OOM, this is definitly a case for a method of the entitiy. In doctrine1 I think whats now a repository was called _Entity_Table
There might be a convention for doctrine2, but the answer to that is not your link.